# WYGWAM text editor overwrites CSS settings in ExpressionEngine

Tags: html, css, wysiwyg, expressionengine, word-wrap

How do I stop WYGWAM (a WYSIWYG editor plug-in) in ExpressionEngine from overriding the css settings that I have in place? I know that some of them don't get overridden because the text is the correct color.

[image]

However, I set the width of the left column which contains the div that contains the WYGWAM entry, and the text WON'T WRAP.

ALSO, what is the difference between CKEditor and WYGWAM?

Just a lowly intern... Thanks so much!

Update:

```
<div id="leftColumn">       
    <div id="landingBodyCopy" class="landingBodyCopyText">
        {landing_body_copy}
    </div>
    <br>

    <div id="graphicLinks">
        {embed="in-store-analytics/retail-analytic" quote="{quote}"}
    </div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
#leftColumn{
    float:left;
    width: 400px;
    bottom: -50px;
    height: 600px;
 }
 #landingBodyCopy {
    width: 400px;
    height: 500px;
 }
```

Comment: Your text won't wrap cause it doesn't seem to have any whitespace to break on.

Comment: Haha right! I got super paranoid when I saw that my example didn't work. Though I figured that it should break in either case. Also, do you know what I could do to override the height aspect?

Comment: For example, when I added breaks inbetween the letters, the text simply overflowed the bottom of the div settings

Comment: There's no way to tell without seeing the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep your text from overflowing its containing div, you either need to allow the div to expand with its contents, or prevent the extra text from being displayed. Depending on which one makes sense for your situation, you need to either remove the `height: 600px` and `height: 500px` from your css, or add `overflow: hidden` to the `#landingBodyCopy` rule.

Comment: Ok here is what I did almost per your advise: I added "overflow: hidden" to the #leftColumn

Comment: As well as getting rid of the height parameter on the BodyCopy

Answer (score 3):

Part of the problem may be that you're using WYGWAM for layout. Usually it's more appropriate to make a field for each block of content on your page. For example, a single field for the main column, and perhaps a drop-down or Playa field to select the right col, or a file field to choose an image for it.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the second part of your question - Wygwam is an ExpressionEngine plugin, which bundles CKEditor (an open source component) and wraps it up to make it play nicely with EE.

To answer the first part of your question - you haven't specified what is getting overwritten by Wygwam that you don't want, so it's hard to help out. I suggest you read up on CSS "importance" though. For example, if you wrap the text area in a div and apply styles based on the ID of that div, they will usually take priority over what wygwam adds (depending on the situation).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the CKEditor clarification. That makes more sense of my google searches for WYGWAM which almost exclusively turned up questions about CKEditor.